# Configuring spring controller properties partially with annotation in class and partially in config xml

Tags: xml, spring, controller, annotations, partial

Is it possible to define few properties of a spring controller with annotation in class and few other properties in spring-servlet.xml. Can we use both annotations and xml config file for same controller or do we use only either of two.i.e. for example,

```
@controller  
@command name annotation  
//some properties  
public class Controller  
{

}
```

and in servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="controller" class = "the classpath">
<property name="someotherproperty" value="somevalue1"></property>
<property name="someotherproperty" value="somevalue2"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do that, because it will mess up. Anybody who will look into your code, will have a problem finding the right configuration for specific part of your project.